# What changes are to be made to run this code?

Tags: java, arrays

```
package com.company;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
public static int Largest(int array[]) {
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
         if (array[i] > largest) {
            array[i] = largest;
        }
        System.out.println(largest);
    }
    return largest;
}

     public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int array[] = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        array[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(array[i]);

    }
    Largest(array);
    System.out.println("largest element is : "+Largest(array));


}
```

}

This is the code to find the largest no. in an array but the output I'm getting for this code isn't desirable. Please check and let me know the problems in this code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: As for your problem, `new int[5]` creates an array of five elements, with indexes from `0` to `4`. The loop `for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)` will use indexes from `0` to **`5`**.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int Largest(int array[]) {
        int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        //for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        //wrong loop range      
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            if (array[i] > largest) {
                //array[i] = largest;
                //wrong assignment 
                largest = array[i];
            }
            System.out.println(largest);
        }
        return largest;
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. What did you change? Why did you make that change? What was the problem with the original code in the question? Please take some time to read [about how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
package com.company;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static int Largest(int array[]) {
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         if (array[i] > largest) {
            largest = array[i];
        }
        System.out.println(largest);
    }
    return largest;
}

     public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int array[] = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        array[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(array[i]);

    }
    Largest(array);
    System.out.println("largest element is : "+Largest(array));
}
}
```

You are wrong on two thing :

- the loops on your array go until index = 5, however your array has a length of 5, so the last index is 4.
- you were assigning array[i] = largest instead of largest = array[i]